# Ho to use a custom mapper with mapstruct with nested values and conditional values

Tags: mapping, mapstruct

I am trying to map one object to another using mapstrut and currently facing some challenges on how to use it for some cases.

```
public class TargetOrderDto {
    String id;
    String preferedItem;
    List<Item> items;
    String status;
    Address address;

}

public class Item {
  String id;
  String name;
}


public abstract class TargetOrderMapper {

  @Autowired
  private StatusRepository statusRepository;

  @Mappings({
      @Mapping(target = "id", source = "reference"),
      @Mapping(target = "preferedItem", source = ""), // Here I need to loop through these values checking for a single value with a specific tag
      @Mapping(target = "items", source = "items"),   // List of objects to another list of different data types. 
      @Mapping(target = "status", source = "remoteStatus") // may need to extract a value from a repository
  })
  abstract OrderDto toTargetOrderDto(RemoteOrder remoteOrder);

}

// Remote Data

public class RemoteOrder {
  String reference;
  List<Item> items;
  String remoteStatus;
}


public class RemoteItem {
  String id;
  String flag;
  String description;
}
```

These are the current scenarios that I have failed to get my head around (maybe I am mapping a complex object).

1. **preferedItem** :
   for this, I need to loop though the items in the order and identify the item with a specific flag. (if it matches then I take that value else I use null)
2. **items** : 
   I need to convert this to a list of 2 different lists; List from List, all have different mapping rules of their own.
3. **remoteStatus** : 
   This one is abit more tricky, I need to extract the status from remoteOrder then lookit up in the db using the **statusRepository** for an alternate mapped value in db.

any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @Gunnar could you kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do business logic with MapStruct. So keep mappings simple and define your own methods were it comes to conditional mappings in list. Note: you can write your own method and MapStruct will select it. Also, from this own implementation you can refer to MapStruct methods again.

```java
public abstract class TargetOrderMapper {

  @Autowired
  private StatusRepository statusRepository;

  @Mappings({
      @Mapping(target = "id", source = "reference"),
      @Mapping(target = "preferedItem", source = ""), // Here I need to loop through these values checking for a single value with a specific tag
      @Mapping(target = "items", source = "items"),   // List of objects to another list of different data types. 
      @Mapping(target = "status", source = "remoteStatus") // may need to extract a value from a repository
  })
  abstract OrderDto toTargetOrderDto(RemoteOrder remoteOrder);

  protected List<Item> toItemList(List<Item> items) {
     // do what ever you want..
     // and call toItem during iterating.
  }

  protected abstract Item toItem(Item item);
}
```

The same goes for status. I added a [FAQ entry](https://mapstruct.org/faq/) some time ago about list (mainly about updating, but I guess the same applies here).

About lookups, you can use `@MappingContext` to pass down a context that contains the logic to access a DB. See [here](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/master/mapstruct-jpa-child-parent)

Comment: Thanks @Sjaak for the help, sorry I had an half-baked idea about mapstruct. Long live